# Vaadin Grid: How to set column order from javascript?

Tags: set, grid, state, vaadin, vaadin23

I want to save and load column settings (width, visibility, order, etc.) for each user in localstorage or on the server (I have not decided yet). To do this, I made my own component, which should be able to load, save and apply grid settings (`<vaadin-state-storing />`).

I think I can get the order. But how do I **set** the order of the columns at the javascript level? (table with default precedence already shown, I want to apply user settings).

Comment: Can you elaborate if you use Vaadin Flow or Hilla and why you want to do this from javascript instead of from a Lit element or java?

Comment: I planned to do it from the JS level, but as a result I handed over the task to the back-end programmer to do it in JAVA (it looks more correct)